# URDF Mesh filetypes?

Tags: ros, geometry, urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are all the possible filetypes I can use in the , <mesh ... /> tag? I'm actually trying to use another URDF file as a mesh filetype, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231588/urdf-mesh-filetypes?/) by [eyn2](https://answers.ros.org/users/26547/eyn2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find a proper reference for it right now, but the mesh formats supported by RViz at least are (from      [wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker - The Marker Message - Object Types - Mesh Resource](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D)):

> Can be any mesh type supported by rviz (binary .stl or Ogre .mesh in 1.0, with the addition of COLLADA (.dae) in 1.1) [..]

So: `stl`, `dae` and `mesh`.

> I'm actually trying to use another URDF file as a mesh filetype, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

No, it's not. If you are trying to 'make multiple copies' of a single model (fi to create four legs or two identical arms), then you should take a look at [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro), which would allow you to *instantiate* multiple instances of a single *macro* (template) and connect it to the right place(s) in your urdf.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eyn2](https://answers.ros.org/users/26547/eyn2/) on 2016-04-11**:
Xacro seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you for your answer